# normalize angles from [-180,180] to [0,180]

Tags: matlab, normalization, angle

I have servo motor can rotate from 0 to 180  only
And I have angles range from -180 to 180 to send to servo
how can i normalize between those two ranges??
And if there is any MATLAB function to do that??
thanks

Comment: What output do you expect for negative angles?

Comment: Add 180 and divide by 2, but you're squashing a whole circle into a half circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could Add 180 and divide by 2 as @High Performance Mark suggests for your specific problem or here is a generalized version of it based on [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43698/range-scaling-problem) post.

**This equation holds good for any limits**

I have written a simple function based on the equation:

```
function [out] = normalizeLim( A,oldL,oldR,newL,newR )

    out = newL*(1-((A-oldL)./(oldR-oldL))) + newR*((A-oldL)./(oldR-oldL));

end
```

**Example:**

```
x = randi([-180,180],1,8); %//  Generating a random vector within the range -180 to 180

>> x

x =

-153  -161    11   101   157  -134    25   -11

>> normalizeLim(x,-180,180,0,180) %// Specifying old and new required limits

ans =

13.5000    9.5000   95.5000  140.5000  168.5000   23.0000  102.5000   84.5000
```

If you want them as integers, you might round them using `round` function

Hope this helps!!