# MATLAB - Generate 2d Array of N random points between 2 values

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, what is the simplest method of creating an array A with N
random points in 2d, where both x and y vary from -100 to 100?

Comment: The simplest way is using `rand`.

Comment: I have made an answer. Could you pls confirm whether that is what you want or if you want something else, i could make changes :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `randi` you could generate Integers between -100 to 100

```
n = 5;
xy = randi([-100 100], n, 2)
```

**Results:**

```
xy =

-62    71
-26    29
 -8   -25
 97   -62
-69   -14
```

---

If you want Non-integers, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30236698/2111163) answer

**Function:**

```
function [out] = normalizeLim( A,oldL,oldR,newL,newR )

    out = newL*(1-((A-oldL)./(oldR-oldL))) + newR*((A-oldL)./(oldR-oldL));

end
```

**code:**

```
out = normalizeLim(rand(n,2),0,1,-100,100)
```

**Results:**

```
out =

 18.8713  -64.2468
-95.4975  -15.4229
-14.9481  -81.1541
-37.4562   19.7047
-67.7031   -5.8151
```